# Counting the number occurances of a word in a comma seperated column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| Movies | Genre(s) of the movie | All Genres | Number of movies for the genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spider Man | action, comedy | action | =countif(B1:B, C1) results 0. it should result 2 |
| James Bond | action, crime, thriller | comedy | =countif(B1:B, D2) results 1. it should result 2 |
| Grown Ups | comedy | crime | =countif(B1:B, D3) results 0. it should result 1 |
| Halloween Kills | Horror | thriller | =countif(B1:B, D4) results 0. it should result 1 |
| Dune | sci-fi | horror | =countif(B1:B, D5) results 1. it should result 1 |
|  |  | sci-fi | =countif(B1:B, D6) results 1. it should result 1 |

So I have something like this in google sheets, is there a way to count the number of movies for each genre. I tried doing what i have in column 4, but only got the number of movies where the genre was the only genre.

Is it possible to do what I want with an if formula in google sheets? For instance, if(there is a match doing regex in this column); count = count+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the below wrong because you are trying to count all movies.

use this

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, "*"&"action"&"*")
```

Use this expression (defunct as I thought you were searching horizontally)

```
=COUNTIF(B1:C1, "*"&C1&"*")
```

C1 can be replaced by a word:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:C1, "*"&"action"&"*")
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, LOWER(B2:B)), ","))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

---

if you got "special" order use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, LOWER(B2:B)), ","))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works as well but you have got to admit @dlystyr's answer is more compact and easy to read. Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: @SaltyBoy not sure whats the real meaning of word "compact" these days xD anyway, you are welcome

Comment: I prefer this solution. The other solution won't fully work if you have genres that contain other genres. For example, if there was a genre called "action comedy", searching for the "action" genre would both find "action" as well as "action comedy". This solution fixes that problem.
(I needed this for counting how many times we played certain games. For example, this solution will work when searching for "7 Wonders" as it won't also count "7 Wonders Duel".)